# Flink what is the proper way to submit args to job from cluster GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, apache-flink

My goal is to pass args to the Main() function of a Flink job via the "Program Arguments" field in the cluster GUI.[image]

And to access them (ideally by key name) in the Main() function some way like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ParameterTool parameter = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

    CustomProps props = new CustomProps (DEFAULT_PROPERTIES_FILE);

    String kafkaAutoOffsetReset = props.getKafkaAutoOffsetReset();
    String cassandraClusterUrl = props.getCassandraClusterUrl();

    if (args.length == 1 && args[0] != null) {

        cassandraClusterUrl = parameter.get("cassandraClusterUrl");
        kafkaAutoOffsetReset = parameter.get("kafkaOffset");
    }

    //Other code...

}
```

I have tried the "ParameterTool" but I don't get anything from it, and if I try something like:

```
kafkaAutoOffsetReset = args[0];
```

It only works if I only put a single word in the "Program Arguments" field. So if I put:

```
blah
```

it says it was set to "blah", but if I try any of these:

```
-kafkaOffset blah
--kafkaOffset blah
-kafkaOffset:blah
-kafkaOffset=blah
```

I get nothing. I know in the CLI an example of how you pass args to a jar is:

```
--input file:///home/user/hamlet.txt --output file:///home/user/wordcount_out
```

But it seems like there is a different way I am missing to do so with the GUI and I am unsuccessful at hunting down documentation related to it.

**TL;DR**

What is the proper way to submit multiple args via the "Program Arguments" field in the Flink Cluster GUI and what is the proper way to access them in Main() function?

Thanks for any and all help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is how arguments have to be passed:
[image]

Comment: so does that mean that we need pass it like -  parameterName="parameterValue"  i.e eg kAKFA_ENDPOINT="localhost" KAFKA_PORT="9092"

Comment: None of the solutions provided here worked for me. I am using flink version 1.10.0 and passing 4 arguments. What would be the problem? Here is the exception:

org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Expected only one value [kafka.brokers="192.168.13.178:9092" kafka-group="group-1" kafka-topic="topic-1" kafka-start-position="latest"]. at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.util.HandlerRequestUtils.getQueryParameter(HandlerRequestUtils.java:59) at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.util.HandlerRequestUtils.getQueryParameter(HandlerRequestUtils.java:47)

Comment: @misterbaykal I am not sure if the format for how arguments are read in via the gui has changed in recent versions, but from the look of your stack trace I think your problem is with what is done with the arguments after they are read into your program. It says "Expected only one value" so I am guessing your method wants an single value and the args when used directly isn't what the method wants. Try setting the values manually in an object in your code and see if that works as a parameter. If it does, then switch to have the args populate that object.

Comment: @Jicaar thanks for the feedback. I tried as you suggested and it did not work. When I run the code from IDE it works without any problem with args setting. But when I deploy it to WebUI it gives the same error. Somehow WebUI needs something in a different way.

Comment: I am using "ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)"

Comment: I resolved my issue by changing "," with "-". Defining arguments with "-" gives error. Correct format: --brokers 192.168.80.160:32772-192.168.80.160:32773-192.168.80.160:32774 --group a-group --inTopic a-topic --outTopic b-topic

Answer (score 10):

Program arguments should be given in flink as shown below

*--custom.key.one custom.value.one --custom.key.two custom.value.two*

Answer (score 0):

Sending the parameters through POST with JSON body is easier and less error-prone due to URL escaping

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/ops/rest_api/

An example POST equivalent would be

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://YOUR_REST_ENDPOINT/jars/YOUR_UPLOADED_JAR_ID/run' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "entryClass": "com.abc.YourMainClass",
    "parallelism": "4",
    "programArgs": "--yourFirstParam=1 --yourOtherCustomArg=something",
    "savepointPath": null,
    "allowNonRestoredState": null
}'
```