How do I add java parameters when creating a job by calling flink API
How do I add java parameters when creating a job by calling flink API
I have tried to search for the corresponding solution, and the solution they give is to add it when the flink client submits the data, as shown below.
But the way I created flink job was by calling API. Are there any suggestions that can solve my problem?
here is the known solution by flink cli:
bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yD env.java.opts: "-javaagent:/opt/flink-1.13.6/skywalking-agent/skywalking-agent.jar=agent.service_name=540yh::calcu-ontime-task,collector.backend_service=192.168.100.22:30180"  --yarnqueue "test"  yourFlinkApp.jar 


See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68828371/2000823

Thank you for your suggestion, but it didn't help me very much. My purpose is not to send parameters to my program. On the contrary, I just want to pass some java agent parameters when flink runs my jar.

Sorry I misinterpreted your question. Maybe https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.19/docs/deployment/config/#yarn-container-start-command-template is more helpful, though I don't see that that option was available with Flink 1.13: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/config/#yarn

Thank you for your selfless answer, does this configuration also apply to kubernetes?
